# Style one word from a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have This sentence:

"Starbucks open-hours are from 7-17. Please choose another time!"

I want to make the numbers "7-17" bold and red so that users can see it easier.

This whole sentence is stored in a @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue:

@Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedPickup") which then in view shows the sentence above.

How can I target the numbers only?

```
 <div class="coffees">
        <div class="message">
            {{if (!data.location.matchHoursPickup) { }}
            {{if (data.location.closedPickup) { }}
            @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedPickup")
            {{  }else{ }}
            {{= data.closedPickupMsg }}
            {{  } }}
            {{ }else{ }}
            {{ if (data.location.closedDelivery){ }}
            @Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedDelivery")
            {{  }else{ }}
            {{= data.closedDeliveryMsg }}
            {{ } }}
            {{ } }}
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: are you trying to say that you can't edit the HTML, so that it would be impossible to add a span tag?

Comment: maybe you should add an umbraco tag for this.

Comment: Umbracos documentation is so unorganized that I cant find If they have the solution for me ....

Comment: Andi I can edit the Umbraco value but it reads the characters only as letters. So it does not read code and then to compile it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the span-tag in the Dictionary value and then use
`@Html.Raw(Umbraco.GetDictionaryValue("BookingStep1_ClosedPickup"))`

/F

Comment: Thanks Frederik I just tried it but It is not working, still showing span tag as a text

Comment: I was able to do it this way, I am sorry did not see that my value is properly wrapped in @html.raw. System is pretty big and I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using a span tag.

For ex:

```
   <p>Starbucks open-hours are from <span id="hey">7-17</span>. Please choose another time!</p>

 CSS:

  #hey {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
    }
```

Comment: as I said the Umbraco dictionary value hold in its self the actual sentence characters but unfortunately I cant write html tags into it because this value this that anything in it should be shown.

So I get something like in the view:

Starbucks open-hours are from <span id="hey">7-17</span>. Please choose another time!

with the span showing i.e. not reading it as a code

Comment: Would give better idea if you could provide more code especially the assignment of message.

Comment: The problem was that umbraco did not read properly the tag. Wrapping it in @html.raw() I was able to do what you wrote!

Answer (score 2):

The [span](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html) tag is the correct way to do this.

> The span element is a generic wrapper for phrasing content that by itself does not represent anything.

HebleV's example works.

Comment: this is what I tried to do but because Umbraco did not read it as a propper tag it was not working. Great answer for people starting with HTML!